# Change PHP include in HTML Page with JS

Tags: javascript, php, html, menu, innerhtml

I'm trying to change the content of the div with "panel_alumno" id using a JS function when a button is pressed so it shows a different table but I can't make it work. When the button is pressed nothing happens.

This is my script:

```
  <script>
   function insertarTablaSolicitudes(){
    document.getElementById('panel_alumno').innerHTML = '<?php include ("tabla_solicitudes_alumno.php") ?>';
   }

   function insertarFormatoSolicitud(){
    document.getElementById('panel_alumno').innerHTML = '<?php include ("formato_solicitud.html") ?>';
   }
```

This is my html body:

```
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a type="button" onclick="cambiarPagina()">Mis solicitudes</a></li>
  <li><a type="button" onclick="insertarFormatoSolicitud()">Enviar Solicitud</a></li>
  <li><a href="cerrar_sesion.php">Salir</a></li>
</ul>

</br></br>

<div id="panel_alumno">

  <?php include ("tabla_solicitudes_alumno.php") ?>

</div>

</body>
```

I've tried different methods to do this but none of them have worked. If anyone know a better way to achieve this, I'd be glad to read it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `include ("formato_solicitud.html")` < for which code is that for?

Comment: Hi, if you "view source" in the browser, it might all make sense.  Maybe there might be some single quotes or something in `formato_solicitud.html`.  Also, if you look in developer tools, and look at the console, you might see some javascript errors if there is a quoting issue.

Comment: It's an HTML that just has a form and a table inside.

Comment: `insertarTablaSolicitudes()` and where are you calling that? Are you running this off a webserver or as `file:///` in your own computer? The question is unclear and there stands to be more questions asked, too many maybe.

Comment: a quick thing to try is replacing the content of `formato_solicitud.html` with `test` - and you should see `test` appear in the dev, and then you'll know that the content messes up the javascript

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, I just checked the browser console and it seems the problem is the PHP code inside the JS script so I changed it to use JS instead of PHP. Here are the new functions that work as intented.

```
<script>
$(function(){ <!--This one puts the default insert when the page is loaded-->
  $("#panel_alumno").load("tabla_solicitudes_alumno.php");
});

function insertarTablaSolicitudes(){
  $("#panel_alumno").load("tabla_solicitudes_alumno.php");
};

function insertarFormatoSolicitud(){
  $("#panel_alumno").load("formato_solicitud.html");
};
</script>
```

And this is my HTML Body:

```
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a type="button" onclick="insertarTablaSolicitudes()">Mis solicitudes</a></li>
  <li><a type="button" onclick="insertarFormatoSolicitud()">Enviar Solicitud</a></li>
  <li><a href="cerrar_sesion.php">Salir</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="panel_alumno">

</div>

</body>
```